# How to stop method execution in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have created a bean named BaseCron that has a method `executeBefore()` that is configured in the below configuration of spring to intercept all method calls of the Crons class and execute before them.

The `executeBefore()` method has some validations. I was earlier validating certain conditions and if they were false, I was throwing an exception. This throwing of exception caused the method to fail and hence the methods in the Crons class did not execute.

It is working fine.

Can you suggest some other way in which I can stop the execution of the Crons class without throwing an exception. I tried return but it did not work.

```
<bean id="baseCronBean" class="com.myapp.cron.Jkl">
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="cron" ref="baseCronBean">
        <aop:pointcut id="runBefore" expression="execution(* com.myapp.cron.Abc.*.*(..)) " />
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="runBefore" method="executeBefore" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Abc class:

```
public class Abc {

    public void checkCronExecution() {
        log.info("Test Executed");
        log.info("Test Executed");
    }
}
```

Jkl class:

```
public class Jkl {
    public void executeBefore() {
      //certain validations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The clean way is to use `Around` advice instead of `Before`.

Update the aspect (*and relevant configuration*) to something like below

```
public class Jkl{
    public void executeAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
       //certain validations
       if(isValid){
           // optionally enclose within try .. catch
           pjp.proceed();  // this line will invoke your advised method
       } else {
           // log something or do nothing
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bond. I however was more confused when else will be executed. Will it not move to the advised method? Does it only go to the advised method when we call pjp.proceed()? Thanks mate.